# C# DacFx package and querying out list of SQLCMD Variables from DACPAC

Tags: c#, sql-server, dacpac

Is it possible using the Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x64 nuget package to query out the list of SQLCMD Variables from a dacpac file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is not much activity here: don't know if DacFx can do this, however DACPAC file is a ZIP archive containing **model.xml** which is the whole body of SSDT project. Unzipping and extracting values can be automated.

SqlCmdVariables in this XML file look like shown below:
[image]

XPath would be `//Header/CustomData[@Category='SqlCmdVariables']/Metadata/@Name`